# Android Preference how to select one of multiple items next to each other

Tags: android, android-preferences, preference, switchpreference

[Preference Example of multiple selections next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nltek.png)

I am trying to add a preference into my PreferenceScreen that allows the user to select one condition from multiple in a single row next to each other (like the image above).

Is there a pre-build way by android of doing that, or will I have to create a custom preference Layout to achieve this. An if yes what is the best way of doing that.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:title="Preferences">
<Preference
    android:key="title"
    android:title="title"
    android:layout="@layout/preference_title"
    />
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="dark_mode"
    android:title="DarkMode"
    android:defaultValue="false"/>

//Instead of Switch Preference for Dark Mode 

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a pre-built preference layout like that. You need to create a custom preference just using a horizontal RadioGroup.

two_inline_button_layout.xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/two_inline_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

your preference xml

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:title="Preferences">

    <InlineButtonPreference
        android:key="dark_mode"
        android:layout="@layout/two_inline_button_layout"
        custom:titleText="DarkMode"
        custom:startText="ON"
        custom:endText="OFF" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

TwoInlineButtonPreference.kt

```kotlin
class TwoInlineButtonPreference : Preference {
    
    ....

    override fun onBindView(view: View) {
        super.onBindView(view)
        val radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.two_inline_button_layout) as RadioGroup
    }
}
```